# Trying to connect 6 different tables to a lookup field, based on results entered into another lookup field

Tags: ms-access

The code below was my attempt to make it work with VBA, but don't know how to link the code in, or it doesn't work?

```
Option Compare Database

    If siteType = "Pennies" Then
        siteModel = TblPennies
    ElseIf siteType = "Nickels" Then
        siteModel = TblNickels
    ElseIf siteType = "Dimes" Then
        siteModel = TblDimes
    ElseIf siteType = "Quarters" Then
        siteModel = TblQuarters
    ElseIf siteType = "Half Dollars" Then
        siteModel = TblHalfDollars
    ElseIf siteType = "Dollars" Then
        siteModel = TblDollars
    End If
End Function
```

I expect form field Model to display only the choices for the Type field entered.  I only get blanks now.  Thank you

Comment: Where is function declaration line  (probably should just be a Sub)? Is siteModel a declared variable? Are you trying to set a combobox RowSource? Need to reference RowSource property to set it. What form event are you executing to call function? Can't refer to table names like that - enclose in quote marks. What you describe sounds like cascading combobox - topic of many threads in many forums.

Comment: Why do you have 6 tables? Do these tables all have same fields? Could be 1 table with another field for coin name.

Answer (score 0):

Assume siteType and siteModel are names of comboboxes. Simplify code.

```
Me.siteModel.RowSource = "Tbl" & Replace(Me.siteType, " ", "")
Me.siteModel.Requery
```

Now figure out what event(s) to put code into. Suggest form Current and siteType AfterUpdate.